# How would I use a hash slice to initialize a hash stored in a data structure?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, slice

In an earlier question I asked how to initialize a Perl hash using slices. It is done like this:

```
my %hash = ();
my @fields = ('currency_symbol', 'currency_name');
my @array = ('BRL','Real');
@hash{@fields} = @array;
```

Now let's imagine a more complex hash, and here is how it is initialized:

```
my %hash = ();
my $iso = 'BR';
$hash->{$iso}->{currency_symbol} = 'BRL';
$hash->{$iso}->{currency_name} = 'Real';
print Dumper($hash);
```

This results in the following:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'BR' => {
                    'currency_symbol' => 'BRL',
                    'currency_name' => 'Real'
                  }
        };
```

Now the question would be: how to initialize this particular hash using the splice method?

Comment: I bumped you up. I have no idea why somebody bumped you down without one explanation--heck, your code is even *formatted*.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even notice. I'm starting to love this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [perllol documentation's Slices section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html#Slices) covers array slices:

> If you want to get at a slice (part of a row) in a multidimensional array, you're going to have to do some fancy subscripting. That's because while we have a nice synonym for single elements via the pointer arrow for dereferencing, no such convenience exists for slices. (Remember, of course, that you can always write a loop to do a slice operation.)
>
> Here's how to do one operation using a loop. We'll assume an `@AoA` variable as before.
>
> ```
> @part = ();
> $x = 4;
> for ($y = 7; $y < 13; $y++) {
>   push @part, $AoA[$x][$y];
> }
> ```
>
> That same loop could be replaced with a slice operation:
>
> ```
> @part = @{ $AoA[4] } [ 7..12 ];
> ```

Extrapolating to hash slices, we get

```
@{ $hash{$iso} }{@fields} = @array;
```

You know it's a hash slice because the “subscripts” are surrounded with curly braces rather than square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, since your hash is declared `%hash`, it would just be `$hash{ $iso }`. `$hash->{ $iso }` refers to a slot in the hash pointed to by `$hash`, which may or may not be pointing to `%hash`.

But once you have that, you can do the following:

```
@{ $hash{ $iso } }{ @fields } = qw<BRL Real>;
```

But as levels soon get complex, it's better to forgo the autovivification luxury and do the following:

```
my $h = $hash{ $iso }{blah}{blah} = {};
@$h{ @field_names } = @field_values;
```

Relocatable pointers within the hierarchy of hashes makes it easier to write anonymous accesses that also allow for easy slices.

Answer (score 1):

`$hash{$iso}` is going to be a hash reference.  You replace what would be the variable name (without the sigil) in a simple slice with a block containing the reference, so:

```
@array{@list}
```

becomes

```
@{ $hash{$iso} }{@list}
```

See http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference